# use extern in C

Tags: c, linux, extern

I try to use some global variable in my project, but don't work. I declared my variable like this:

In file kernel.h :

```
extern DBConnection * conn;
```

And, in my other file, called kernel.c, i do this:

```
#include "kernel.h"

int get_info() {
    conn = (DBConnection *) malloc(sizeof(DBConnection));
}
```

But, at compile, i received an error that is:

```
/home/fastway/VFirewall-Monitor/kernel.c:19: undefined reference to `conn'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided a declaration but you also need a **definition**. Add this to your `kernel.c`, at the top after the include:

```
DBConnection * conn;
```

Comment: @VitorLuis That's what the header is for, so all translation units see the same declaration. But you also need exactly one definition - the linker will pick it up and "fix" the other translation units.

Comment: @Vitor-Luis Actually this is not a compiler error, but the error found during linker stage. 

Because for compilation, the extern declaration is more than enough where compiler got to know a object and its type where declared in some other file.

Answer (score 2):

`extern DBConnection * conn;`

declares the variable without defining it.

You need to add a file scope definition in one source file, for example in kernel.c:

`DBConnection * conn;`

Answer (score 2):

`extern` doesn't allocate memory for the variable it qualifies, it only allows it to be used. You'll need a declaration of `conn` without the `extern`. You could add this to your kernel.c:

```
DBConnection * conn;
```

Comment: *extern doesn't allocate memory for the variable it qualifies* that's not true in the general case. With an initializer it also defines it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
#include "kernel.h"
DBConnection * conn
int get_info() {
    conn = (DBConnection *) malloc(sizeof(DBConnection));
}
```

You need to add the file scope of conn in kernel.c

Answer (score 1):

The `extern` keyword simply states that there is a variable somewhere in the final linked binary that has that name and type, it doesn't define said variable. The error message you're getting is about not being able to find the definition that the extern is referring to.

Define your method in your .C file, outside of any function definition.

Answer (score 1):

to use a variable in many files declare it outside a function in any file and then use the `extern nameofvar` to use it in the other files example
file 1 :

```
int externalvar; 

main(void)
{
    //stuff ...
}
```

file 2 :

```
extern externalvar;

void someFunc(void)
{
   externalvar = 5;
  //stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a compiler error, but the error found during linker stage. Because, for compilation, the extern declaration is more than enough where compiler got to know a object and its type where declared in some other file. As long as the compilable file .c file knows the object declared somewhere than it will not throw any error. so the below code snippet in .c file also will **not** throw any compilation error.

```
extern DBConnection * conn
int get_info() 
{
   conn = (DBConnection *) malloc(sizeof(DBConnection));
}
```

But in the linker stage the kernel.o(object file) while linking looks for the real location of this objects reference, by that time if it is not able to find this object defined in some other object file than an linker error will be thrown.